# My Discord XP bot isn't recognizing user data in JSON files?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot is not working as planned.
For the context of the bot, I followed a YouTuber's tutorial almost exactly (other than the algorithm for the experience) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKkrCHnun0M&t=890s

```
async def update_user(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        print('added new user')
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1

async def add_xp(users, user, exp):
    print('added exp')
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp
```

I added the print function so I could track which functions have been triggered.
The first time, it worked. User data popped up in my users.json file when i typed in the channel. However, upon the second time typing anything, this happens:

[image: users.json]

It showed the same data being input twice! I was so confused because everything is the same. I will post the full code of the bot in here. Please help me make the bot possible to use.
https://pastebin.com/BkzSbVan (I removed the server ID and channel ID, so please focus on the functions)

Comment: you should ask where do you get the user.id from in that json you show? if you check for it it should be exist in the json you read and write out. As far as i see there is no id in the json.

Comment: all the big chunk of numbers in there IS the user id @MarkusRosjat, the ones that were highlighted in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) requires keys to be strings, so when you use `json.dump`, it converts the integer IDs into strings. However, when you load that back with `json.load`, it stays a string, so the `user` dictionary will have string keys when you load it from the file. Then, when you check if the user ID is in the dictionary, it's by integer, so it's not, and it adds the integer ID as a key for the dictionary with a new initial value. At this point, you have an integer and string version of the same ID in your dictionary. When you write this back to the file with `json.dump`, it again converts the integer ID to a string, resulting in what you see in your screenshot.

Comment: IT worked! thanks so much, I listened to your advice and changed ALL user.id into str(user.id), now its working like a charm!